# Google Apps Script Copy Range If Condition Met

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, typeerror

I have two spreadsheets, source and destination. In source I have data sheet and in destination I have archive sheet. In data sheet J column contains percentages. I am trying to workout a script which automatically copies the range (A:I) of the rows that has greater than 10% in the J cell to append in the archive sheet.

I'm stuck at this point:

```
function CopyRange() {
  var sourcespread = SpreadsheetApp.openById('aaa'); //replace with source ID
  var sourcesheet = sourcespread.getSheetByName('bbb'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
  var destspread = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ccc'); //replace with destination ID
  var destsheet = destspread.getSheetByName('ddd'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name
  var testrange = sourcesheet.getRange('J:J');
  var testvalue = (testrange.setNumberFormat("0.00").getValues());
  var data = [];
  var j =[];
  //Condition to check in J:J, if true, copy the same row to data array 
  for (i=0;i<testvalue.length;i++) {
    if (testvalue[i] >= 10) {
    data.push.apply(data,sourcesheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,3).getValues());
  //Copy matched ROW numbers to j
    j.push(i);
}  
}
  //Copy data array to destination sheet
  destsheet.getRange(destsheet.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

I'm getting error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (line 19, file "cp3")

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @Marios attached the screenshot, kindly take a look

Comment: then `1.8>10` will evaluate to **false**.  This is why you are getting the error.

Comment: @Marios that's the first row... there are many rows that are above 10

Comment: true.. Is this the source sheet ? (`bbb`) or the destination sheet (`ddd`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Issue:

```
if (testvalue[i] >= 10)
```

- This condition is never satisfied, therefore `data` is a 1D array (=`[]`) and not a 2D array. Therefore,

  - `data`=[]
  - `data[0]` =`undefined`(has no value in index `0`)
  - `data[0].length` => Throws:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (line 19, file "cp3")

The reason the  condition is never satisfied is because

> In data sheet J column contains percentages

The value of `10%` is `0.1`(10/100) and NOT `10`.

#### Solution:

- Use 0.1 instead of 10
- In addition, As the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64102060/) mentions , `testValue` is a 2D array.  Although implicit conversion to `number` will take place, it is preferable to use proper index:

  ```
  if (testvalue[i][0] >= 0.1)
  ```

#### To read:

- [What does the range method getValues() return and setValues() accept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720612/what-does-the-range-method-getvalues-return-and-setvalues-accept)
- [Best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Answer (score 1):

### Issue:

- `testvalue` is a 2D array of values, therefore in the if condition
  you are comparing a **row** with a **value**, instead of a **value** vs
  **value**. Therefore, you should [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the array: `var testvalue = testrange.setNumberFormat("0.00").getValues().flat();`

---

### Solution:

```
function CopyRange() {
  var sourcespread = SpreadsheetApp.openById('aaa'); //replace with source ID
  var sourcesheet = sourcespread.getSheetByName('bbb'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
  var destspread = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ccc'); //replace with destination ID
  var destsheet = destspread.getSheetByName('ddd'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name
  var testrange = sourcesheet.getRange('J:J');
  var testvalue = testrange.getValues().flat();
  var data = [];
  var j =[];
  //Condition to check in J:J, if true, copy the same row to data array 
  for (i=0;i<testvalue.length;i++) {
    if (testvalue[i] >= 10) { 
    data.push.apply(data,sh.getRange(i+1,1,1,3).getValues());  
  //Copy matched ROW numbers to j
    j.push(i);
}  
}
  //Copy data array to destination sheet
if(data.length!=0){destsheet.getRange(destsheet.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);}
}
```

Comment: I was the one  who [wrote the original script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48691791). Over time, I've seen various copy pastes on this site itself. All without even  attempting to remove my signature comment: `//Copy matched ROW numbers to j`. So, I know `push.apply` works. It was one of my first attempts to `flat`(Those days We didn't have `flat` :)).

Comment: @TheMaster yes I noticed my mistake. Sorry for that :) I voted up your answer :)

Comment: @TheMaster please don't take it offensive... Thank you for the script, I tried multiple threads to find a way... but didn't see that, I'll credit the original post from next time...  if I plainly ask what I want, ppl say I didn't even try... I'm trying to learn by example and also by the hard way. Hope you'd understand

Comment: @Nix It's ok. But if I may ask, where did you find the script?

Comment: @TheMaster https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56261647/google-apps-script-copy-rows-from-one-sheet-containing-todays-date-into-anoth

Comment: @Marios I changed it accordingly but the error comes... J:J contained formula and I made the change (*100) so it comes as desired but still I'm getting the same error

Comment: @Nix could you please share a screenshot of J column? It would really help us identify the issue.