# adding in if function so HTML table only has certain rows

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to implement a create HTML table based on rows then email script, so far that part is working, the problem comes when I try to only send certain rows to the table that is then sent

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var ss  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName('2021')//rename sheet name per your file;
  var headers = ws.getRange('A1:H1').getDisplayValues()//get table headers name;
  
  //assign variable to each header value
  var name = headers[0][0]; 
  var leavetype = headers[0][1];
  var fromDate = headers[0][2];
  var toDate = headers[0][3];
  var totaldays = headers[0][4];
  var status = headers[0][5];
  var reportingmanager = headers[0][6];
  var checksum = headers[0][8];; 

  const lr = ws.getRange('B1').getValues()

  var tablerangeValue = ws.getRange(2,1,10,8).getDisplayValues()//get range value, my data range start from 4th row and has 7 columns, pls chage per your need;

  if (checksum == 2);

  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('emailTable');

  htmlTemplate.name = name;
  htmlTemplate.leavetype = leavetype;
  htmlTemplate.fromDate = fromDate;
  htmlTemplate.toDate = toDate;
  htmlTemplate.totaldays = totaldays;
  htmlTemplate.status = status;
  htmlTemplate.reportingmanager = reportingmanager;
  htmlTemplate.tablerangeValue = tablerangeValue;

  var htmlForEmail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
  
  var toEmail = 'jonathon.banks@westal.com.au';
  var ccEmail = 'jbjono4@gmail.com';

  MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: toEmail,
  cc: ccEmail,
  subject: "Flyscreens Overdue",
  htmlBody:htmlForEmail
     });

}
```

this is the HTML that I'm currently using

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
  table, th, td {
  border: 0px solid black;
  font-size:15px;
}

th, thead {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

</style>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th><?= name ?></th><th><?= leavetype ?></th><th><?= fromDate ?></th><th><?= toDate ?></th><th><?= totaldays ?></th><th><?= status ?></th><th><?= reportingmanager ?></th>
        </thead>
        <tbody >
          <? tablerangeValue.forEach(r => {?>
          <tr> 
          <td><?= r[0] ?></td><td><?= r[1] ?></td><td><?= r[2] ?></td><td><?= r[3] ?></td><td style="text-align:center"><?= r[4] ?></td><td><?= r[5] ?></td><td><?= r[6] ?></td>
          </tr>
          <?})?>
         
        </tbody>

      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

like I said so far if grabs all of the rows and places it into the table but I only want certain rows to be put into the table

I have an IF function in the sheet that generates a 1 when an email should be sent or a 2 when it shouldn't, this is based on the due date in the row, if the date is earlier then today then it generates a 1 if the due date is later then today then it generates a 2

any help would be great

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `I have an IF function in the sheet that generates a 1 when an email should be sent or a 2 when it shouldn't, this is based on the due date in the row, if the date is earlier then today then it generates a 1 if the due date is later then today then it generates a 2`, I cannot imagine your Spreadsheet. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: i have a spreadsheet information of orders I process at my work, A:H have data concerning the order including date ordered, in column i, I have the following formula(=IF(AND(C3<today(),E3="Ordered"),1,2)) this produces a 1 if the order is over due, what i want the script to do is put the rows with 1 in it into a HTML table which is then sent to me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Apps Script Copy Range If Condition Met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64101924/google-apps-script-copy-range-if-condition-met)